# HTML CSS LI Wrapping

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a vertical menu in my system which is basically made of HTML `ul`/`li` with CSS styling (see image below). However I don't want the `li` items which are wider than the menu to wrap, I would prefer them to overflow with a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the menu. How can I do this in CSS?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
ul {
  overflow: auto;  // allow li's to overflow w/ scroll bar
                   // at the bottom of the menu
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap; // stop the wrapping in the first place
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `white-space:nowrap`. Like so:

```
li {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Here's some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 3):

You would also need to give the style the ul:

```
ul{
 width:250px;
 overflow:auto;
}
```